# Tasks delay not working when called from cmd

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery, celery-task

I am running celery worker in one cmd and from shell, I am running my task, but when I call my task like `TestTaskOne.delay()` it's not working, cmd just pause there and I have to terminate with `ctrl+c` and worker is also not getting any task.

Any ideas why this is happening.

for celery worker I am using `celery -A Project worker -l info -P eventlet`

**tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import task

@task
def TestTaskOne():
    msg = "DEFAULT   TASK   IS   WORKING......"
    return msg
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os, logging
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab


# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'RestUserAPI.settings')

app = Celery('UserAPI')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "mongodb"
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_MONGODB_SCHEDULER_DB = "celery"
CELERY_MONGODB_SCHEDULER_COLLECTION = "schedules"
CELERY_MONGODB_SCHEDULER_URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
```

Answer (score 0):

I explored celery docs and seems like i missed to add celery app in my project `__init__.py`

After adding these line, delay function is working.

**__init__py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```